# Why isn't angularFire binding to scope after previous unbind/disassociate?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

What I'm attempting is: on login, add the profile information to the scope then, on logout use the disassociate callback(unbind) so one users gunk doesn't mix with the next.

It works on the initial login but after logout, login fails. Any suggestions? I've noticed this with disassociate in general.

```
    $scope.$on('angularFireAuth:login', function(){
        //attach current profile info to scope
        angularFire(fbUrl + 'profiles/user-' + $scope.auth.id , $scope, "profile",{}).
        then(function(unbind){
            console.log($scope.profile);
            $scope.$on('angularFireAuth:logout', function(){
                    //detach current profile info from scope
                    unbind();
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Also.. is there a better way to use the callback.

Comment: How does the login fail? No users are able to authenticate?

Comment: **** it wasn't failing. My test data had duplicated values. Sorry @Hiattp.. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Np, I'd recommend taking that event listener out of the callback though, just to clean it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, you can't have duplicate values :). Since you also asked if there is a better way to use the callback, here are some additional thoughts. I suggest removing the logout event listener from the promise callback for a couple reasons:

1. You might eventually want to do other things with that event that aren't related to the login event, so you want to maintain separation of concerns.
2. You might want to unbind the profile info elsewhere in the app, so it makes sense to attach it to the `$scope` anyway.

You might want to do something more like this:

```
$scope.$on('angularFireAuth:login', function(){
  //attach current profile info to scope
  angularFire(fbUrl + 'profiles/user-' + $scope.auth.id , $scope, "profile",{}).
  then(function(unbind){
    $scope.unbindProfile = unbind;      
  });
});

$scope.$on('angularFireAuth:logout', function(){
  //detach current profile info from scope
  if($scope.unbindProfile) $scope.unbindProfile();
});
```